# How to avoid the overflow of the icons while the windows size reduce to minimum

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to design a nav-bar using flex-box, with bootstrap 4. I have three div and whenever the browser shrinks, the div's `header__center` and `header__right` are coming one another line. But I wanted to make them remain in the same line, no matter how small the size of the device.

Now when the device width is `576` to `614` i am getting this problem:

[image: 6]

And when the device size is extra small that is `<314`, there is this problem
[image]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav.navbar {
  align-content: center;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 75);
  padding: 0px 20px;
  /* REMOVED TOP PADDING */
}

.fas .fa-search {
  color: #65676b;
}

.header__left>img {
  height: 40px;
}

.header__left {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__input {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #eff2f5;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 999px;
}

.header__input>input {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline-width: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.header__center {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}


/*modified css */

.header__center__option {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  height: 60px;
}

.header__center__item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 0 2vw;
  height: 60px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px #f8f9fa, inset 0 -3px #f8f9fa;
}

.header__center__item.active,
.header__center__item.active:hover {
  color: #1877f2;
  /* border-bottom: 1px solid #1877f2;
  border-bottom-width: 3px; */
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
}

.header__center__item:hover {
  background-color: #e9ebef;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.header_option-link {
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 52px;
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  justify-content: center;
  color: gray;
}

.header__center__item.active>.header_option-link {
  color: #1877f2;
}

.header_option-link:hover {
  color: gray;
}

.header__center__item.active {
  color: #1877f2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1877f2;
  border-bottom-width: 3px;
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  border-top-right-radius: 1px;
  border-top-left-radius: 1px;
  right: 2px;
  left: 2px;
}

.header__info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 12px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 18px;
  border-top-right-radius: 18px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 18px;
  border-top-left-radius: 18px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.header__info__name {
  font-size: 0.9375rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #050505;
  margin-top: -4px;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
  line-height: 1.3333;
}

.header__right {
  display: flex;
}

.header__info>span {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.header__items {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #e4e6eb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
}

.header__info img {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
}

.header__info:hover {
  background-color: #e4e6eb;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light py-xl-0 py-md-0 py-sm-0 py-2">
  <div class="header__left">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Free_logo.svg/600px-Free_logo.svg.png" />
    <div class="header__input">
      <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
      <input class="d-none d-xl-flex" placeholder="Search Facebook" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="header__center d-none d-xl-flex d-md-flex d-sm-flex">
    <ul class="header__center__option">
      <li class="header__center__item active">
        <a class="header_option-link text-decoration-none" href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-plane fa-lg"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="header__option-line"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="header__center__item">
        <a class="header_option-link text-decoration-none" href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-bed fa-lg"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="header__option-line"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="header__center__item">
        <a class="header_option-link text-decoration-none" href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-bus-alt fa-lg"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="header__option-line"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="header__center__item">
        <a class="header_option-link text-decoration-none" href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-umbrella-beach fa-lg"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="header__option-line"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="header__center__item">
        <a class="header_option-link text-decoration-none" href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-spa fa-lg"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="header__option-line"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="header__right">
    <div class="header__info">
      <img src="https://www.clipartkey.com/mpngs/m/118-1188761_avatar-cartoon-profile-picture-png.png"></img>
      <span class="header__info__name">User</span>
    </div>
    <div class="header__items">
      <i class="fas fa-envelope-open-text"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

How to make those icons not to come in another line and be responsive to whatever the size the device width is decreased? Any help would be appreciated!

I am thinking to use the media query but stuck on the idea to start on what should be the approach or the techniques to make on that same line.

Comment: Have you tried to use a media query? it should do the trick

Comment: I am using the bootstrap so, didn't try using the media-query, can you help on what should be the approach to `make on that line`. I can try using media query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `padding-left: 10px` on class `header__center__option`.

Remove all the class `fa-lg` on your icons.

Adding below stuff if you want to make it scrollable.

```
nav.navbar{
  ...
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/290478rf/1/

Comment: but there is still a problem in smaller devices!  that is when the width decreased to <314. the div `header__right` is coming downward.

Comment: What's your expected layout on width equals 200px?

Comment: to be scrollable. and also if there are few more icons on the div `header__right`, the first problem still persists.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kbo0us3L/, when adding some more icons on `header_right` that problem repeats. so maybe removing `padding-left: 10px` is not a solution?

Comment: Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/290478rf/1/

Comment: yeah, that looks fine, can you update the answer with the changes you made?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to move `header__left`, `header__center__option` and `header__right` to one parent.

Change

```html
<div class="header__left">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Free_logo.svg/600px-Free_logo.svg.png" />
    <div class="header__input">
      <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
      <input class="d-none d-xl-flex" placeholder="Search Facebook" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="header__center d-none d-xl-flex d-md-flex d-sm-flex">
    <ul class="header__center__option">
      <li class="header__center__item active">
        <a class="header_option-link text-decoration-none" href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-plane fa-lg"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="header__option-line"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="header__center__item">
        <a class="header_option-link text-decoration-none" href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-bed fa-lg"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="header__option-line"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="header__center__item">
        <a class="header_option-link text-decoration-none" href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-bus-alt fa-lg"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="header__option-line"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="header__center__item">
        <a class="header_option-link text-decoration-none" href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-umbrella-beach fa-lg"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="header__option-line"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="header__center__item">
        <a class="header_option-link text-decoration-none" href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-spa fa-lg"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="header__option-line"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="header__right">
    <div class="header__info">
      <img src="https://www.clipartkey.com/mpngs/m/118-1188761_avatar-cartoon-profile-picture-png.png"></img>
      <span class="header__info__name">User</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

to

```
<div>
<div class="header__left">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Free_logo.svg/600px-Free_logo.svg.png" />
    <div class="header__input">
      <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
      <input class="d-none d-xl-flex" placeholder="Search Facebook" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="header__center d-none d-xl-flex d-md-flex d-sm-flex">
    <ul class="header__center__option">
      <li class="header__center__item active">
        <a class="header_option-link text-decoration-none" href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-plane fa-lg"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="header__option-line"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="header__center__item">
        <a class="header_option-link text-decoration-none" href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-bed fa-lg"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="header__option-line"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="header__center__item">
        <a class="header_option-link text-decoration-none" href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-bus-alt fa-lg"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="header__option-line"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="header__center__item">
        <a class="header_option-link text-decoration-none" href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-umbrella-beach fa-lg"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="header__option-line"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="header__center__item">
        <a class="header_option-link text-decoration-none" href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-spa fa-lg"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="header__option-line"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="header__right">
    <div class="header__info">
      <img src="https://www.clipartkey.com/mpngs/m/118-1188761_avatar-cartoon-profile-picture-png.png"></img>
      <span class="header__info__name">User</span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Now hide and show `header__center__item` on respective breakpoints. This will fix both of your problems.

Comment: can you format the changed code properly? and show how is it working? I didn't find any changes?

Comment: oh just added a new div without class?

Comment: Notice that the code in the second block is wrapped inside a `div`.

Answer (score -1):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav.navbar {
  align-content: center;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 75);
  padding: 0px 20px;
  overflow: hidden;

  /* REMOVED TOP PADDING */
}

.fas .fa-search {
  color: #65676b;
}

.header__left>img {
  height: 40px;
}

.header__left {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__input {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #eff2f5;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 999px;
}

.header__input>input {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline-width: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.header__center {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}


/*modified css */

.header__center__option {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  height: 60px;
}

.header__center__item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 0 2vw;
  height: 60px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px #f8f9fa, inset 0 -3px #f8f9fa;
}

.header__center__item.active,
.header__center__item.active:hover {
  color: #1877f2;
  /* border-bottom: 1px solid #1877f2;
  border-bottom-width: 3px; */
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
}

.header__center__item:hover {
  background-color: #e9ebef;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.header_option-link {
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 52px;
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  justify-content: center;
  color: gray;
}

.header__center__item.active>.header_option-link {
  color: #1877f2;
}

.header_option-link:hover {
  color: gray;
}

.header__center__item.active {
  color: #1877f2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1877f2;
  border-bottom-width: 3px;
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  border-top-right-radius: 1px;
  border-top-left-radius: 1px;
  right: 2px;
  left: 2px;
}

.header__info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 12px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 18px;
  border-top-right-radius: 18px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 18px;
  border-top-left-radius: 18px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.header__info__name {
  font-size: 0.9375rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #050505;
  margin-top: -4px;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
  line-height: 1.3333;
}

.header__right {
  display: flex;
}

.header__info>span {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.header__items {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #e4e6eb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
}

.header__info img {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
}

.header__info:hover {
  background-color: #e4e6eb;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light py-xl-0 py-md-0 py-sm-0 py-2">
  <div class="header__left">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Free_logo.svg/600px-Free_logo.svg.png" />
    <div class="header__input">
      <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
      <input class="d-none d-xl-flex" placeholder="Search Facebook" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="header__center d-none d-xl-flex d-md-flex d-sm-flex">
    <ul class="header__center__option">
      <li class="header__center__item active">
        <a class="header_option-link text-decoration-none" href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-plane fa-lg"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="header__option-line"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="header__center__item">
        <a class="header_option-link text-decoration-none" href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-bed fa-lg"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="header__option-line"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="header__center__item">
        <a class="header_option-link text-decoration-none" href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-bus-alt fa-lg"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="header__option-line"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="header__center__item">
        <a class="header_option-link text-decoration-none" href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-umbrella-beach fa-lg"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="header__option-line"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="header__center__item">
        <a class="header_option-link text-decoration-none" href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-spa fa-lg"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="header__option-line"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="header__right">
    <div class="header__info">
      <img src="https://www.clipartkey.com/mpngs/m/118-1188761_avatar-cartoon-profile-picture-png.png"></img>
      <span class="header__info__name">User</span>
    </div>
    <div class="header__items">
      <i class="fas fa-envelope-open-text"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Do you like to write something about what you have changed?